# Web Analytics in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-analytics, site-usage

I last looked at this a year back and at that point, it was still not addressed and was a topic in the Office 365 uservoice (started back in 2015!). But I have not been able to find anything regarding updates (or tracking) for this much needed feature. Does anyone have any access to any updates on this?

P.S. this is my research on the topic. In Sharepoint Online, you can get to Site Web Analytics Reports page (below url append) but that will indicate that Usage Logging is disabled on the tenant.

```
/_layouts/15/UsageDetails.aspx
```

Another place was Security and Compliance tile under Office 365 for Audit log search (needs to be enabled by tenant admin), but I am not seeing that as being evolved into meaningful OOTB usage analytics solution (more of logging/auditing)

Office 365 user voice for Usage reports: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/7194558-usage-reports-for-sharepoint

Old (Apr 2016) MS response for not supporting Site Analytics in SP Online: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/web-analytics-in-sharepoint-online/fee15d10-00e5-4496-89e4-ccad70ef1802

Comment: Have you look at or consider Office 365 Adoption Preview Content Pack with PowerBI?

Comment: I did take a look, but again that looks like a solution for Adoption insights.. I am looking for something which does traditional Site Analytics (e.g. page hits, url clicks, referrals). There are ISV's like Cardiolog that do similar analytics for SP Online. Maybe, this is a space that ISV's have taken a hold of and MS does not want to invest resources in trying to develop it?

Comment: What about this: https://www.sharepointeurope.com/add-google-analytics-sharepoint-without-modifying-master-page/

Comment: Yup, I have been using Google Analytics since SP 2013 for analytics and was just checking to see if Online, there was any progress made to capture and present analytics OOTB.

Comment: You can use /_layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx?view=11

Answer (score 0):

In case someone like me is still looking for an answer,
`yoursite/_layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx?view=19` is where I found the OOB analytics report for our sites.